# Remove special character from string?

Tags: java, string

i have String like

```
Join our<\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;Worldwide Host Your Own Screening Tour!
```

and i want

```
Join our Worldwide Host Your Own Screening Tour!
```

My Code::

```
String str = "Join our<\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;Worldwide Host Your";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;", " "));
```

Error

```
 Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Comment: what does your code result in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String str = "Join our<\\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;Worldwide Host Your";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("<\\\\/strong>\\u00a0<strong>&#8220;", " "));
```

[`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,+java.lang.String%29) expects an RegEx.

You could use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) too (it is a bit simple):

```
StringUtils.replace(str, "<\\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
    String s="Join our<\\/strong>\u00a0<strong>&#8220;Worldwide Host Your Own Screening Tour!";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<\\\\/strong>\\u00a0<strong>&#8220;", " "));
```

Francisco wins.